# Which herbs are cooked and which go raw, when making fish pate

Tags: seasoning, salmon, pate

I'm cooking a salmon pate. I intend to use parsley, rosemary, garlic, pepper and lemon as seasoning. I'm not sure which of these I should cook with the salmon, and which should go in the blender? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raw garlic isn't to everyone's taste so should be cooked. The flavour of rosemary is also best cooked, or even infused and removed as it can be rather dominant if you find a big bit. You may want to be gentle with the rosemary the first time. I assume you're poaching or steaming the fish.

Lemon and parsley are usually added raw.

Black pepper can be used raw or cooked. Cooking softens the flavour and allows it to spread through a dish, but adding a little more at the end allows for adjustments to the flavour.